# Why does bash insert quotes I didn't ask for?

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone explain this to me, please?

```
$ set -x
$ export X="--vendor Bleep\ Bloop"; echo $X
+ export 'X=--vendor Bleep\ Bloop'
+ X='--vendor Bleep\ Bloop'
+ echo --vendor 'Bleep\' Bloop
--vendor Bleep\ Bloop
$
```

Specifically, why does the `echo` line insert `'` characters that I didn't ask for, and why does it leave the string looking unterminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Understanding Shell Expansions

Bash performs [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) in a set order. The -x flag allows you to see the intermediate results of the steps that Bash takes as it tokenizes and expands the words that compose the input line.

In other words, the output is operating as designed. Unless you're trying to debug tokenization, word-splitting, or expansion, the intermediate results shouldn't really matter to you.

Answer (score 2):

(Good question)

the ' chars aren't really there.

I would describe what you see as the `-x` features attempt to disambiguate how it is handling keeping your string intact. The `+` sign at the front of separate line with `echo` in it shows you that this is shell debug/trace output.

Note that the final output is exactly like your assignment, i.e. `X=...`

IHTH

Comment: So, you're saying this is a bug (or at least a misunderstanding) about how `-x` outputs commands bash is about to run? You may be right, but I'm reluctant to blame 23 year old software for something simple like this without a better reason.

Comment: Sorry, not a bug, working as designed. Best explanation is @CodeGnome's reference to order of expansion AND that `-x` is designed to let you see how the order is being processed. Put another way, "it's a feature"! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion seems to be arising more from this `+ echo --vendor 'Bleep\' Bloop`. The reason it appears like that is because it is printing what it would look like when you expand `X`. In other words doing `$X` evaluates to putting the independent "words" `--vendor`, `Bleep\`, and `Bloop` on the command line. However, this means that `Bloop\` is a word and to prevent the `\` from being interpreted to escape the  (space), it is preserving the `\`. If these are meant to be parameters to a different command, I would suggest doing either:

```
export X='--vendor "Bleep Bloop"'
```

or

```
export X="--vendor \"Bleep Bloop\""
```

but I'm 100% not sure if either work. If you want to store parameters to a command you could do:

```
# optional:
# declare -a ARGS
ARGS=('--vendor' '"Bleep Bloop"')
```

And then use them as:

```
echo ${ARGS[@]}
```

Comment: But for the real command instead of `echo`, double quotes would be necessay.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
echo --vendor 'Bleep\' Bloop
```

produce the exact same output as

```
echo "--vendor Bleep\ Bloop"
```

Bash is only reinterpreting your code into it's own code via the debug/trace option.
Reasons for this are probably historical and should not be cared about.

Comment: I disagree that it 'should not be cared about' but I think you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you `set -x` you are telling Bash to print its interpretation of every command you put in.

So when you put in

```
export X="--vendor Bleep\ Bloop"
```

Bash sees it as

```
export 'X=--vendor Bleep\ Bloop'
```

and prints as such.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the echo has `'Bleep\' Bloop` when I didn't use any `'` in my export, nor why it's `\'` and no termination on the `''` string